# E in exponential regression equation

Tags: functions, notation, scientific-notation

Hello I came across an exponential regression equation in excel and I was wondering what did the "E" stand for? the equation is : y=5E-09e^0,0139x [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oh7Tp.png) Can someone please help me by showing what the E stands for and the answer for my equation.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is a common way that some programs express numbers in [scientific notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation). 5E-09 means $5 \times 10^{-9} = 0.000000005$.